# How would you design a table to keep track of users' likes and dislikes in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I'd like to get your views on designing a table to store users' likes and dislikes so that people can check a user's like/dislike history. Suppose I have a catalog of thousands of products. Each of them can be liked or disliked. I'm thinking about creating two tables `likes` and `dislikes`, with each row containing an user id, product

`user_like` table

```
user_id     product_id     
 Tom          toyA
 May          toyZ
 Peter        toyD
 Tom          toyZ
 Peter        toyV
```

`user_dislike` table

```
user_id    product_id
 Tom         toyB
 Tom         toyU
 May         toyV
 Paul        toyA
 Paul        toyN
```

Is that an appropriate approach? Or should I do it in one table `user_like_dislike` using concat to append new like to the end of a record,for example:

`user_like_dislike`

```
user_id     like           dislike
  Tom     toyA,toyZ        toyB,toyU
  May     toyZ             toyV
  Paul                     toyA,toyN
  Peter   toyD,toyV
```

Comment: One table with a a PK of (user_id,product) and a tinyint (0 or 1) for dislike/like

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would have just one table, user_likes, with columns like so:

```
user_likes (user_id, product_id, like_type)
```

Have like_type be a 1 to indicate a like, and a 0 to indicate a dislike.

Use a primary key on user_id and product_id (a user should not be able to like and dislike the same product)

Answer (score 0):

asuming you have numbers instead of names for the user_id and product_id columns, the first approach would be better.

although your row-count goes through the roof, it is a lot faster.

you can either search by user-history of by product-history, which is quite complicated (and therefor slow) in the second approach

you can even combine the 2 tables `user_like` and `user_dislike` by adding like `like TINYINT(1) UNSIGNED NOT NULL`

Comment: Opinion's fine but what about some, cold, hard facts

Comment: It still doesn't stand up to scrutiny, I'm afraid. You have made 2 or 3 substantive statements above. Can you prove any of them?